# Hide Ajax.ActionLink after click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to hide ActionLink after click using code below, unfortunately it do not works. Maybe someone could point me in right direction?

```
@foreach (var conversionModel in Model)
{
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete file", "DeleteFile", "Converter", new { id = @conversionModel.ProcessId }, null,
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            OnSuccess = "hideLabel"
                        })
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    function hideLabel(){
        $(this).hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Its because

```
$(this)
```

I dont think "$(this)" works here so put a class to your ActionLink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete file", "DeleteFile", "Converter", new { id = @conversionModel.ProcessId, class ="myclass" }, null,
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            OnSuccess = "hideLabel"
                        })
```

and use

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function hideLabel(){
        $('.myclass').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When using a class all buttons will be hidden. If you want to hide  the active actionlink only, you need to pass the id of the actionlink to the javascript function.